# How to format/prepare plots for manuscript in scientific publications

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, libreoffice-writer, publishing

Hllo All,

A very simple question and I am sorry to ask it here, but I am having a big time with it to solve it..And here is the question again..I have few  figures in .svg, .png and pdf formats..I wanted them in libreoffice inorder to write a scientific report... And so I followed the regular method ..Inser-->image-->from file-->and so I have the figure in libreoffice..But the inserted figure is not of good qulaity as i have shown in the example below..But in reality the those figures have good resolution both in pdf and png formats..

for example when I do copy and paste the figures from Excel it looks as

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbHwe.png]

And I looking for something like this to make , As I have many figures to format
http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v17/n11/images/nn.3816-F2.jpg

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. ([How to format/prepare plots for maunuscript in scientific publications](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61191)). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: Hello Dacid, I was asked to do post the question here..Please let me know where can I find the solution..and where to post..?

Comment: Posting here is fine (posting in two places is not). However your question is not very clear.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question again...

Comment: To avoid cross-posting, delete the question from academia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [YouTube video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjFoPLumJvKAhXHRyYKHWaHA5kQtwIILDAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dk9qUH9qGIGM&usg=AFQjCNGtcV9pzjhrq4dm8PoUDnKdV2z8Qg&sig2=fCqCH0uXJYddF0DEuvP9Sg) shows an example of inserting an image correctly.  Try to follow the steps in the video and see if the problem still occurs.

It may help to prepare the image ahead of time to the proper size using graphics software such as [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).  See
[Why do images copied to Libre Office Writer look so pixelated?](https://superuser.com/questions/880756/why-do-images-copied-to-libre-office-writer-look-so-pixelated)

It may also help to upgrade to LibreOffice 5, as suggested here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/58049/imga-render-quality-very-bad-how-to-fix/

It could be that the image was not inserted at the proper resolution or ratio.

Or it could be that the compression settings were set too high when exporting from LibreOffice to PDF.  (I did not understand from the question whether you are exporting from LibreOffice or just seeing the problem in LibreOffice on screen).